# Extruding buildings from OS MasterMap data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I've downloaded OS MasterMap with the intention of extruding buildings to their respective heights. I wrongly assumed that I would receive shapefiles of the buildings which I'd then extrude using the height data in the attribute table but instead comes as a shapefile called 'TopographicArea'.

I've imported this shapefile and linked the included building heights csv file but how do I go about extracting just the buildings and extruding them to their heights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the attribute data for the Topographic Area layer.  Simply select all entities that have a theme of "(1:buildings)" (or the featurecode = 10021).  You may want to save your selection to a separate shapefile for convenience.

In ArcScene follow the Help Documentation:

- [Extruding features by an attribute value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/3d-analyst/extruding-features-by-an-attribute-value.htm) and
- [About using extrusion as 3D symbology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/3d-analyst/about-using-extrusion-as-3d-symbology.htm).